# Calling php scripts using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am making a chat script and an hoping to code it so that when a user submits a message, the script will run `chat_new.php` and then refresh `#cbox`. I use the code below to try and accomplish this, but unfortunately it won't reload. Just to rule it out, I tested without any jQuery and `chat_new.php` executes without problems, so it definitely is my ajax script. In addition, `getUpdates()` works just fine on it's own. I only have a problem when posting new messages through ajax.

```
<div id="cbox" align="left">
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(function() {
            getUpdates()
        }, 2000);
    });

    function getUpdates() {
        $("#cbox").load("/lib/chat_post.php");
    }

    $("#submitmsg").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/lib/chat_new.php',
            data: {
                submitmsg: 'submitmsg',
                usermsg: 'usermsg'
            },
            success: function() {
                getUpdates()
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
</div>
<form name="message" method='post' id="cbox_input">
    <input name="usermsg" id='usermsg' type="text" size="63" maxlength="255" />
    <input name="submitmsg" id='submitmsg' type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: can you post your `chat_post` and `chat_news` php files?

Comment: @DimalChandrasiri added them. (:

Comment: @DimalChandrasiri why request files that are working? Just adds unnecessary noise in the code within question that isn't needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues:

Your click handler exists before the element it references and is not inside `document.ready`. Therefore it can't find the element and never gets bound to it

Once that is fixed you need to prevent the default form submit process. Otherwise page will reload on submit

```
// put this inside ready()
$("#submitmsg").click(function (event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   //other code
})
```

Comment: Oh, this seemed to have fixed it right up! It now loads just as I want it, but I fear I may have improperly declared the `data: ` because every message is now `usermsg`

Comment: Yes...you hard coded those. Simple fix `data: $('#cbox_input').serialize()`

Answer (score 1):

This might be a simple as moving `});` from the third line of your script, to just before `</script>` so that your function and your ajax call are inside `$(document).ready(...` and therefore only get processed once the DOM has loaded, and all HTML elements are on the page.